# Why is Redux Provider tag breaking the entire App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to integrate React Toolkit app into a project.
However, I am getting the following error.

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {},
})
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <EventTemplateProvider>
    <AuthState>
      <SetStripeLayout>
        <EventState>
          <TicketState>
            <AlertState>
              <Provider store={store}>   <===== Provider
                <BrowserRouter>
                  <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
                    <Switch>
                      <Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        render={(props) => <App {...props} />}
                      />
                      <PrivateRoute
                        path="/dashboard"
                        render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} />}
                      />
                      <PrivateRoute
                        path="/template"
                        render={(props) => <EventTemplate {...props} />}
                      />
                      <PrivateRoute
                        path="/events"
                        render={(props) => <Events {...props} />}
                      />
                      <AdminRoute
                        path="/admin"
                        render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />}
                      />
                      <Route
                        path="/readmore/:id"
                        render={(props) => <VirtualEventReadMore {...props} />}
                      />
                      <Route
                        path="/*"
                        render={(props) => <Error404 {...props} />}
                      />
                      <Redirect from="/" to="/" />
                    </Switch>
                  </Suspense>
                </BrowserRouter>
              </Provider>
            </AlertState>
          </TicketState>
        </EventState>
      </SetStripeLayout>
    </AuthState>
  </EventTemplateProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I did not start coding anything for redux.
and when I remove Provider tag, the app works.

Can anyone tell me why it is breaking apart?

thank you in advance.

modified index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <h1>Hello </h1>
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: provided code looks fine, u need to provide code snippets where u are making use of Hooks, ie useDispatch, useSelector or any function starting with word 'use'

Comment: Can you try to move the Provider up on the hierarchy? Maybe on the top.

Comment: Maybe the provider should be on the top

Comment: `I am trying to integrate React Toolkit app into a project.` What did you do? Did you use npm/yarn to add it? You can try deleting yarn.lock or package.lock.json and node_modules then install everything again.

Comment: I even removed everything in the index.js and still it does not work. there is no hooks, no other components. I am so confused.

Comment: `Provider` does use hooks internally, but this is almost always a build issue. As the error says, this is possibly due to having more than one copy of React in `node_modules` . Can you use a tool like `yarn why react` or `npm ls react` to see if there's more than one React installed?

Answer (score 0):

Check Pacakage.json file if the modules are installed or not.Make sure that you have installed these pacakges:-

```
npm i @reduxjs/toolkit
npm i react-redux
```